# Como armazenar o resultado de uma iteração em uma nova variável usando python?

Tags: python, pandas

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou analisando um `conjunto de dados de compartilhamento de bicicletas`. Nesse `dataset` existe uma coluna chamada `'birthyear'`, que indica o ano de nascimento do usuário.

Estou tentando transformar essa coluna em uma coluna de série temporal. Para fazer isso, criei a seguinte iteração:

salvei essa coluna em uma variavel chamada `yr`

```
for i in yr:
    x = datetime(yr[i],1,1)
    print(x)'
```

A saída é:

```
1964-01-01 00:00:00
1986-01-01 00:00:00
1967-01-01 00:00:00
1976-01-01 00:00:00
1991-01-01 00:00:00
1975-01-01 00:00:00
1975-01-01 00:00:00
```

Mas quando armazeno a saída na variável `'x'`, ela não armazena essa lista, mas apenas a primeira linha.

```
Saída: datetime.datetime(1975, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: teria como postar o código de yr aqui?

Comment: `yr = dataframe.birthyear`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você pode adicionar elementos em uma lista python usando `append`

```
x=[]
for i in yr:
    x.append(datetime(yr[i],1,1))

print(x)
```

Isso vai adicionar todas as iterações do loop na lista `x`, da maneira que você demonstrou no seu código, a cada iteração a variável `x` é sobrescrita, no final do loop a variável `x` só terá armazenado o valor da ultima iteração.

Comment: Muito obrigado !